# Spring data - domain object inheritance and generic methods

Tags: java, generics, jpa, spring-data

I have some domain objects:

```
@Entity
public class Log {

}

@Entity
public class LogLetter extends Log {

}

@Entity
public class LogAction extends Log {

}
```

and I want to have only one repository which allows me to get Log's childs.

Can I do teoretically something like this?

```
public interface LogRepository extends CrudRepository<Log, Long> {

    @Query("select from ?1)
    public <T> List<T> getLog(Class<T> clazz);

}
```

and call this method:

```
List<LogLetter> logLetters = getLog(LogLetters.class);
```

Exist any other approaches to do what I described?

Comment: Why won't you just create `LogLetterRepository` and `LogActionRepository`? They are cheap and you get `findAll` for free.

Comment: These two domain objects were only an example, actually I have 15 of these objects and creating new repository for every domain object is not too elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible out of the box (especially given the fact that you cannot use parameters in `from`), but you can implement it as a custom method (see [1.4. Custom implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)):

```
public <T> List<T> getLog(Class<T> clazz) {
    return em.createQuery("from " + clazz.getSimpleName()).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement it using `#{#entityName}`:

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM #{#entityName} o where o.attribute1=:attribute1")
Page<T> findByAttribute1Custom(@Param("attribute1") String attribute1, Pageable pageable);
```